# Hangman in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

When I run the code, it doesn't replace the dashes with the letters, but it adds it onto the existing dashes. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
a = 0
new = ""
while a < limit:
  for i in range(len(formula2)):
    if (formula2[i] == partial_fmla[i]):
      new[i] = new + partial_fmla[i]
    elif (formula2[i] == guess):
      new[i] = guess
    else:
      new = new + "-"
```

Comment: 1) This code was not pasted properly. 2) We could really use some context.

Comment: It shouldn't run at all.  You would get index error at `new[i]`

Comment: Python strings are immutable, so surely assigning to `new[i]` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Posting some extra code could help but after looking at your code, I think there is a mistake in this line:

```
new = new + "-"
```

You are adding dash(`-`) to new, meaning you are not replacing anything here but you are adding an extra dash(`-`) to new.